# How to use bpy.ops.macro - defining macro steps

Tags: python

I found this code and tried to understand it. As far as I understand macro allows step by step execution. But I struggle to make it work right.

As far as I understand one has to define what each macro command is
and then generate an operator that works off each macro command - right?

*Sadly the Blender Python manual does not explain the use of macro well, or I did not find it.*

Here is the code I have:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Macro


# Our finalizing operator, shall run after transform
class Finalize(Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.finalize"
    bl_label = "Finalize"

    def execute(self, context):
        print("DONE!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class Make(Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.make"
    bl_label = "Make"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}



# Macro operator to concatenate transform and our finalization
class Test(Macro):
    bl_idname = "TEST_OT_Test"
    bl_label = "Test Macro"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Note that we have to register classes first before populating
        # the Macro operator    
        bpy.utils.register_class(Finalize)
        bpy.utils.register_class(Make)
        bpy.utils.register_class(Test)


        # The important bit: populate the macro operator with a sequence
        # of existing other operators
        Test.define("test.make")
        Test.define("test.finalize")
        return {'FINISHED'}

# BUTTON
class ObjectData(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Object + Mesh Data"
    bl_idname = "ObjectData"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Modeling Toolbox"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        self.layout.operator("TEST_OT_Test")



# END     
def register(): bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
def unregister(): bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I think it should be more like this:  https://gist.github.com/zeffii/6cff6d0f2d98ccdb97e7

Comment: I pasted the code into the text editor and executed it - it generates the button but when pressing it nothing happens.

Comment: yeah, it only works from spacebar as far as i can tell..  (as the file name suggested)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a corrected version: the Test.define needed different values.
Works perfect now - even including calling the transform and waiting till that is done so you script can continue with the next command/macro!

The transformation is started via calling **Test.define("TRANSFORM_OT_translate")** between the first and last macro step.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Macro


#End : Snap 3D Cursor and delete empty
class Finalize(Operator):
    bl_idname = "s3dc.finalize"
    bl_label = "Finalize S3DC"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
        bpy.ops.object.delete();
        print("DONE!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

#Start : Create the empty
class Make(Operator):
    bl_idname = "s3dc.make"
    bl_label = "Make S3DC"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')       
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add()       
        print('Started')
        return {'FINISHED'}

#Execute : Start the macro sequence
class S3DC(Macro):
    bl_idname = "s3dc.trigger_macro"
    bl_label = "S3DC Macro Sequence"

# UI Button in Tool Shelfe
class ObjectData(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Object + Mesh Data"
    bl_idname = "ObjectData"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Modeling Toolbox"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("s3dc.trigger_macro", text="Run Set 3D Cursos macro")

# END     
def register(): 
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    S3DC.define("S3DC_OT_make")
    S3DC.define("TRANSFORM_OT_translate")  # This starts the transformation command 
    S3DC.define("S3DC_OT_finalize")    

def unregister(): 
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: you have called a modal op inside non-modal, so the snapping was done before the end of the transform op ( cursor doesn't move )

Comment: Oh yes true - maybe I made a mistake because the functions where working. I noticed that sometimes you have to restart Blender to flush out some behaviors.

Comment: I cannot in the script find any command for the transformation. You added "Test.define("TRANSFORM_OT_translate")". This this line itself call the translate/grab mode?

Comment: yes it starts the `transform.translate` operator

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: you mean `TRANSFORM_OT_translate` to `transform.translate` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34408/discussion-between-claas-kuhnen-and-chebhou).

Comment: yes in deed - I started a chat if you want to join

Comment: So, did you guys ever get this working or...
I've been having a go with this as a reference, but I'm not getting anywhere. Partly because the syntax has changed slightly since 2016, but even adjusted for 2.93 I'm not getting the macro to do what it should.
More details here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/277843/149985